# lexical scoping and environments in R

Tags: r, lexical-scope

I have following code snippet inspired by my original code:

```
func2 <- function(foos) {
  for (foo in foos)
    print(eval(parse(text = foo)))
  return(foos)
}

func1 <- function(vec) {
  text3_obj <- 'text3'
  vec <- c(vec, c('text3_obj'))
  return(func2(vec))
}

text1_obj <- 'text1'
text2_obj <- 'text2'
func1(c('text1_obj', 'text2_obj'))
```

Here in main code I am creating 2 objects (`text1_obj` & `text2_obj`) and passing their names to `func1()`. This function after adding another object in vector, calls `func2()`. In `func2()` I am simply printing the values of the objects. Below is the output of this code:

```
[1] "text1"
[1] "text2"
Error in eval(parse(text = foo)) : object 'text3_obj' not found
```

After going in debug mode I realized even `exists('text3_obj')` from inside `func2()` throws error. so I have 2 questions:

1. Even though `func1()` is immediate parent environment of `func2()`; why `text3_obj` is not parseable inside `func2()`. Even higher up global environment variables are parseable e.g. `text1_obj`.
2. Why explicitly naming environment in debug mode works like charm e.g. `exists('text3_obj', where = parent.frame())` and `eval(parse(text = 'text3_obj'), parent.frame())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the "calling environment" with the "enclosing environment."  Check out these terms in Hadley's book "Advanced R."

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

The "calling environment" is the environment from which a function was called, and is returned by the unfortunately-named function `parent.frame`.  However, the calling environment is not used for lexical scoping.

The "enclosing environment" is the environment in which a function was created and is used for lexical scoping.  You have created both `func1` and `func2` in the global environment.  Therefore, the global environment is the "enclosing environment" for both functions and will be used for lexical scoping *regardless of the calling environment!!*

If you want `func2` to use the execution environment of `func1` for lexical scoping, you have (at least) two options.  You can create `func2` within `func1`

```
func1 <- function(vec) {

  func2 <- function(foos) {
    for (foo in foos)
      print(eval(parse(text = foo)))
    return(foos)
  }

  text3_obj <- 'text3'
  vec <- c(vec, c('text3_obj'))
  return(func2(vec))
}
```

then your test works as expected:

```
> text1_obj <- 'text1'
> text2_obj <- 'text2'
> func1(c('text1_obj', 'text2_obj'))
[1] "text1"
[1] "text2"
[1] "text3"
[1] "text1_obj" "text2_obj" "text3_obj"
```

Alternatively, you can create `func2` and reassign it's "enclosing environment" from within `func1`.

```
func2 <- function(foos) {
  for (foo in foos)
    print(eval(parse(text = foo)))
  return(foos)
}

func1 <- function(vec) {
  text3_obj <- 'text3'
  vec <- c(vec, c('text3_obj'))
  environment(func2) <- environment()
  return(func2(vec))
}
```

This will also work as expected.

An interesting tidbit I found while writing my demonstration code...  It appears that when you re-assign the environment of `func2` from within `func1`, R creates a copy of `func2` in the execution environment of `func1`.  By the time you get back to the console, the enclosing environment of the original `func2` remains unchanged.  Witness:

```
a = function() {
  print(identical(environment(a), globalenv()))
}

b = function(x) {
  environment(a) <- environment()
  a()
}
```

Test `a()` and `b()`:

```
> a()
[1] TRUE
> b()
[1] FALSE
> a()
[1] TRUE
>
```

This was not what I expected, but seems like really excellent behavior on the part of R.  If this were not the case, the enclosing environment of `a()` would have been permanently changed to the execution environment of `b()`, and `FALSE` should have been returned the second time `a()` is called.

If fact, it turns out you can force the change to the original `a()` in the global environment using `<<-`:

```
a = function() {
  print(identical(environment(a), globalenv()))
}

b = function(x) {
  # set a variable in the execution environment of b() for use later...
  montePython = "I'm not dead yet!!"
  # change the enclosing environment of a() in the global environment
  # rather than making a local copy of a() in b()'s execution environment.
  environment(a) <<- environment()
  a()
}
```

Test `a()` and `b()`:

```
> a()
[1] TRUE
> b()
[1] FALSE
> a()
[1] FALSE
>
```

Interestingly, this means that the (normally temporary) execution environment of `b()` persists in memory even after `b()` terminates, because `a()` still references the environment, so it can't be garbage collected.  Witness:

```
> environment(a)$montePython
[1] "I'm not dead yet!!"
```